# Java - Adding a time variable to the current time

Tags: java, datetime, java-time, duration

I am trying to add a given "duration" to the current time. For example,

```
String runtime = "1h58m"
```

and I am trying to add this to the current time so that the output looks something like

```
The runtime of <movie name> is <runtime>. 
<Name> will end at <calculatedDate>
```

where calculated date is the system current time, plust the given runtime.

This is what I currently have, but don't know how to add the runtime to current system time.

```
public void playMovie(Movie movie){
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/Y hh:mmaa");
        Date date = new Date();
        System.out.println("The runtime of "+name+" is "+runtime);
        System.out.println(""+name+" will end at "+df.format(date));
```

Comment: Don't use `Date`, but `java.time`, which makes this straightforward.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `ZonedDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 2):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:** I recommend you use [`java.time.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) which was introduced with *Java-8* as part of [JSR-310 implementation](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/pfd/jsr310/JSR-310-guide.html) to model [ISO_8601#Duration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations).

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String runtime = "1h58m";
        runtime = "PT" + runtime;
        Duration duration = Duration.parse(runtime);
        System.out.println(duration);

        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
        LocalDateTime endTime = now.plus(duration);
        System.out.println(endTime);

        // Custom format
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/uuuu hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
        System.out.println(endTime.format(dtf));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
PT1H58M
2021-09-11T23:03:58.749831
09/11/2021 11:03 PM
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/zwKuV7)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Comment: This is the smart answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just use LocalDateTime API (since java 8) like that:

```
System.out.println("will end at " + LocalDateTime.now().plusHours(1).plusMinutes(30).plusSeconds(45));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the LocalTime class as shown below.

```
public void playMovie(Movie movie){

        // Finding Hours, Minutes, and Seconds from the String runtime
        int n = runtime.length();
        int hours = 0;
        int minutes = 0;
        int seconds = 0;
        int i=0;
        for(int j=1; j<n; j++){
            if(runtime.charAt(j)=='h'){
                hours = Integer.parseInt(runtime.substring(i,j));
                i=j+1;
            }
            if(runtime.charAt(j)=='m'){
                minutes = Integer.parseInt(runtime.substring(i,j));
                i=j+1;
            }
            if(runtime.charAt(j)=='s'){
                seconds = Integer.parseInt(runtime.substring(i,j));
                i=j+1;
            }
        }

        //SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/Y hh:mmaa");
        //Date date = new Date();
        System.out.println("The runtime of "+name+" is "+runtime);
        //System.out.println(""+name+" will end at "+df.format(date));
        
        // Current System Time using the LocalTime class
        LocalTime currentSystemTime = LocalTime.now();  

        // Adding the duration of the movie to the current system time
        LocalTime movieEndTime = currentSystemTime
                .plusHours(hours)
                .plusMinutes(minutes)
                .plusSeconds(seconds);

        System.out.println(""+name+" will end at "+ movieEndTime);
}
```